# How setup reverse proxy for SSH server?

Tags: sshd, reverse-proxy

I have a VM with network interfaces, namely `eth0`, `eth1`, and `eth2`. All of these interfaces are connected to independent ISP routers which have globally static IP configured let's say `Public-IP1`, `Public-IP2`, and `Public-IP3`. Internally each of the ISP routers offers an IP to the VM let's say `Internal-IP1`, `Internal-IP2`, and `Internal-IP3` on the respective interfaces connected with the router. I have forwarded port 22 on all the VM interfaces to Public-IPs of the ISP routers.

Now when I try to `ssh` to `Public-IP1`, I am able to reach the VM but I am unable to reach the VM on `Public-IP2` and `Public-IP3`. For testing, if I enable only one of the network interfaces on the VM I am able to login to the VM from the corresponding Public-IP. For eg, if only the `eth2` interface is active on VM, then I am able to reach VM through `Public-IP2` over `ssh`.

The problem happens only when more than one network interfaces are active. In that case, only the first interface accepts connection while others remain unreachable.

I would like to know if there is some kind of configuration required to achieve a setup where the VM becomes accessible over all the three Public-IPs at the same time.

First I tried setting up `netplan` but it did not make any difference although the service is running without error. Config is available here https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fxQkJMbtmb/ - exact paste from `/etc/neplan/network.yaml`

Next, I updated `/etc/network/interfaces` which did bring up the interfaces properly but landed me into the problem mentioned above. Config is available here - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/X5Vsy86z9M/ - exact paste from `/etc/network/interfaces`

I have also setup the tables at `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` just listed the names. Config is available here - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4ykJp3W5cK/ - exact paste from /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

Route list is available here - https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/b9JNTd9yHW/

Comment: It sounds like your network routing rules are incorrect - that you've got conflicting gateways.  Do you have your netplan configuration for your machine for all three interfaces?

Comment: I have updated the configs on the question itself. Do you see if anything has been missed?

Comment: YOu *really* should not revert to ifupdown and `/etc/network/interfaces` if you have netplan on your system.  The two will fight hard.

Comment: But what should I do? Netplan just acts as if it's not there. Whatever I do it neither gives any error nor do the settings take effect. Even the netplan service is running properly, so is the networking service.

Comment: Ah, I think i see where you're doing it wrong...

Answer (score 1):

With your Netplan configurations, you're specifying the default gateways still for **all three interfaces**.  You need to pick **one** to be the Default interface.

This configuration **negates your routing tables** and uses DHCP to define your gateways - which won't work because that sets the system-wide default gateway.

We need to adapt it - disable the DHCP-assigned routes, and just let the addressing alone get assigned.

You'll also need your configuration set up proper for routing, and I think you were trying to overcomplicate the configuration.

Try using this configuration in your netplan configs:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 192.168.0.1
         table: 1000
      routing-policy:
       - from: 192.168.0.0/24
         table: 1000
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.10,192.168.0.20,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
    eth1:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-routes: false
      routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 192.168.1.1
         table: 1001
      routing-policy:
       - from: 192.168.1.0/24
         table: 1001
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
    eth2:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-routes: false
      routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 192.168.2.1
         table: 1002
      routing-policy:
       - from: 192.168.2.0/24
         table: 1002
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

**This has some assumptions in play though**, namely that (1) your networks are /24, (2) you want to DHCP your network but NOT have gateways defined for the other two interfaces (so eth0 is your primary, and eth1 and eth2 are just sitting on the other network but not the primary gateways), and (3) you are actually using Netplan.

Comment: I tried this but for some reason, netplan is having no effect on my system. It's not even able to bring up the interfaces. The way things are working is to write to /etc/network/interfaces. Also, I rebooted the system and now everything works as intended with the settings listed in the question. I am not sure if it's the interfaces file alone or in combination with netplan but I feel netplan has no effect.

Comment: Also I feel that interfaces file is implementing the same plan as you have attempted with netplan. I will update netplan config and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: If you removed Netplan and went to ifupdown then netplan won't work, but you need to remove the interface configurations from `/etc/network/interfaces` for netplan to work.  ALSO, your /etc/network/interfaces is accepting DHCP gateways, that routing will break things because of the DHCP components.  You don't have the luxury of the overrides there, so that's a consideration.  What my config in netplan does is **disables** the accepting of the DHCP routes (default gateway as defined by DHCP) for the other two interfaces.